# Access java object attributes in MULE jdbc:query

Tags: esb, mule

I have an instance of Java class `InsurancePolicyStatus` (insurancePolicyStatus) that has     attribut "String policyId".

Instance of this class is saved using following code :

```
message.setSessionProperty("insurance_policy_status", insurancePolicyStatus)
```

How to access `insurancePolicyStatus.policyId` in value attribute in the jdbc query?

```
jdbc:query key="messageUpdateSuccessStatus"
    value="UPDATE message  SET [UpdateTime] = GETDATE(), 
         [Status] = 'SUCCESS', 
         [ResultId]=#[header:SESSION:insurancePolicyStatus.messageResultId]
    WHERE [MessageId] = #[header:SESSION:id]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the expression

```
#[groovy:message.getProperty('insurance_policy_status',org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.SESSION).getPolicyId ()
```

where you need policyId value. getPolicyId() should be your java method to get policyId property.

Regards.